# Guardar variable Javascript en PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una variable en JavaScript que consigo enviar a un `value` de un `form` en html.
El input donde se carga la variable está como `hidden` porque no quiero que muestre en pantalla el valor. El formulario solo tiene ese `input`y un botón para enviar el formulario por method `POST` a un fichero PHP donde quiero que almacene la variable.
La cuestión es que no lo hace...

No sé que me falta o qué estoy haciendo mal. Pongo el código aquí.

**Fichero JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById("puntos").setAttribute("value",highscore);
```

Utilizo esto para enviar al `value`del input del formulario y funciona.

**Fichero HTML**

```
<form action="rank_insert.php" method="post">
    <input id="puntos" name="puntos" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guardar" />   
</form>
```

**Fichero PHP**

```
<?    
$puntos = $POST['puntos'];

echo "Puntos: ".$puntos;
?>
```

Y aquí es donde aparece solo el texto "Puntos: " y nada más... Es como si no se pasase la variable.

Comment: Intenta con `document.getElementById("puntos").value = highscore;`

Comment: $puntos = $POST['puntos']; en esa linea prueba a cambiarlo por $puntos = $REQUEST['puntos'];

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo ser tan tonto?? Gracias Sacha

Comment: No olvides evaluar previamente con `isset` o con `empty`, no sea que tu error_log se llene de mensajes `Undefined index` en casos en que ese dato no sea enviado. Mi forma preferida es usar `empty`  con un *operador ternario*: `$puntos=(empty($_POST["puntos"])) ? "" : $_POST["puntos"];` De ese modo tendrás el valor posteado o nada en la variable `$puntos`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema esta en que tratas de acceder la variable `$POST` para ver los datos del formulario cuando en realidad el nombre de la variable es `$_POST`.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Totalmente... Estaba tan ofuscado que no veía el problema... eso es de primero de PHP xDDD